# Node js callbacks

Tags: node.js, express

Есть:

```
    router.get('/calc',callbacks1,callback2);
```

Как передать результат вычисление колбек функции callbacks1 в колбек функцию callback2?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - запихать результат первой функции в объект запроса или ответа. Насколько помню, в доке экспресса, предлагается использовать `res.fields` для этих целей. Соответственно, куда положили в первой функии, оттуда же достаем во второй.

Answer (score -2):

```
router.get('/calc',callbacks1);

var callbacks1 = function(arg) {
    // ... some code
    callbacks2(some_arg);
}

var callbacks2 = function(arg) {
    // ... some code
}
```